# values change in c++ code

Tags: c++, variables, runtime

following code set the value of n and K to zero why this happens??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{   int n,K;
    cin>>n>>K;
    cout<<n<<" "<<K<<endl;
    int arr[n];
    int ranged = (1<<n);
    int dp[K][ranged];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   for(int j=0;j<ranged;j++)
            dp[i][j]=0;
    }
    cout<<n<<" "<<K<<endl;
}
```

for input 
5 3
output:
5 3
0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't *set the value of n and K to zero*, you just set the 2D array `dp` to `0` inside the `for` loop. Moreover you create

```
int dp[K][ranged];
```

But in `for` loop you checked `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` and assigned `dp[i][j]=0;` which can buffer overflow.

Change `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` to `for(int i=0;i<K;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You should most probably get `Segmentation Fault`. *Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you.”*

Your outer `for` loop goes from `1` to `n` but the number of rows you declared in your 2D array was `K`. So as long as `n<=K` your code should run fine but if you give `n>k` ( *as 5>3* ) then you should get a segmentation fault ( or undefined behaviour as you are getting!).

Either change

`for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` to `for(int i=0;i<K;i++)`

or

`int dp[K][ranged];` to `int dp[n][ranged];`